# How do I send a value from a button group in html to my php code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

Hi, 
I have html code that allows a user to upload an image and then allows them to choose a level of difficulty for that image. However, I need to pass the value of that button (or whatever button is selected to my php code to be processed). For example, if they choose novice level, I want to set a variable in my php code to 1, and if they chose advanced, I would want the variable to be set to 2.

My code in html is as follows:

```
    <form id="formUploadFile"  action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" > 
    <p> 
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>"> 
    </p> 

    <p align="left"> 
        <label for="file" >First, Choose your image!</label> 
        <input type="file" name="files[]"  /> 
    </p> 
    <p class="text-center"> 
        <h5>Then, Choose your Difficulty!</h5>
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">


                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="difficultybutton" value="0" onclick="loadingCircle()">Kids</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="difficultybutton" value="1" onclick="loadingCircle()">Novice</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="difficultybutton" value="2" onclick="loadingCircle()">Intermediate</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="difficultybutton" value="3" onclick="loadingCircle()">Advanced</button>
              </div>
```

How do I go about passing the values of these buttons to the php code? My loadingCircle() code just hides everything on the page and displays a loading circle while my php code processes.

Comment: Use a radio or dropdown list. PHP has no way to know which button was selected unless you disable the other buttons with JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with **Airerr** using `<select>` or `<input type="radio"/>` would be better for this but since your question states *"How do I go about passing the values of these buttons to the php code?"* Where is the relevant `php` where you have attempted to get the value of the submitted `button`?

Comment: Also in your `php` where you get the form data you can just use `$_POST['difficultybutton'];` and that will have the value of which ever button the client has submitted. Are you using `ajax` to submit the form data because if so then this is where you might run into other issues due to duplicating the `button` names. Please give more information about how you are submitting the form and show more relevant source code please. Thank you.

Comment: The php code im trying to run is in the action portion of the form at the top, shows as action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" So once one of these buttons is selected, that php code is run immedietly after (with a loading circle shown on this current screen so the php can run in the background). The issue I'm having is that I'm not able to access the chosen button value when the php code is loaded for some reason...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code maybe help you understand

I suggest you to chose radio buttons but I have example with button also

```
<form action="" method="post">

  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1">Kids
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2">Novice
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Intermediate
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3">Advanced

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>


<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if(isset($_POST['radio']))
   {
   echo "You have selected :".$_POST['radio'];  //  Displaying Selected Value
  }
?>
```

### with buttons

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="submit" value="0" name="zero">
</form>


<?php 
  if (isset($_POST["zero"])){
   echo $_POST["zero"];
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I didn't use radio buttons because I'm not sure how to run a function from the radio button (like i did with onclick="loadingCircle()". Is there a way to do so? Also, when I try your suggested method for using buttons, I get this error from my php page:  Undefined index: difficultybutton   -- I feel like the value isn't being transferred between the two pages